# Angular 2: Use service before bootstraping module

Tags: angular

Is it possible to use service before bootstrapping the module in Angular 2 application?

```
myService.myMethod();
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Answer (score 0):

After your exports, add :

```
export function myFactory(myService: MyService) {
  return () => myService.doSomething();
};
```

Finally add this to your app.module providers

```
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: myFactory,
      deps: [MyService],
      multi: true
    }
```